# Open a document that is in in a folder on the desktop on another computer

Tags: vb.net

I wrote a programme that must work on different computers. There are some files in a folder that is placed on the desktop. Now I want to open that file from the programme that I wrote and that works fine on my computer (see code below):

```
If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists("C:\Users\Public\Desktop\black\test.doc") Then
        Process.Start("C:\Users\Public\Desktop\black\test.doc")
    Else
        MsgBox("No test.doc found!")
    End If
```

When I run the programme on another computer then it doesn't work. It only works when I place the file on the desktop and not in a folder (see code below):

```
Dim thepath As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
    Process.Start(thepath & "\test.doc")
```

The idea is to keep the desktop clean without all the files that are stored in the folder on the desktop.

Who knows the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop is pointing as the users desktop e.g C:\Users\Fred Bloggs\Desktop.

you want Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonDesktopDirectory for public.

and use Path.Combine to build up your file name it's in System.io, with lotsof other good stuff.